# c# Open "Select location" window in OneNote

Tags: c#, office-interop, onenote

I'm creating OneNote note via Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote.
After creating I want to open OneNote's "Select location in OneNote" window: 
[image: Select location in OneNote]

Is it possible to choose a notebook for new note, if so where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look at the Quick Filing interfaces:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj680122.aspx

Comment: Many thanks! Strange name but it works: app.QuickFiling().Run()